# Loop through one list to see if any usernames corresponds to other list Python

Tags: python, list, loops

So if a list called new_users is to be looped through and check if any names corresponds to an other list called current_user, how would one go about this task? Additionally .append those new users to the current list.

```
import time, sys
c_users = ['admin', 'eric', 'eon', 'joseph', 'anton', 'oscar', 'pontus']
n_users = ['joseph', 'eon', 'yasmina', 'jeremiah', 'mugabe']
actually_new_users = list(set(n_users) - set(c_users))
c_users = list(set(c_users).union(set(n_users)))

if not c_users:
      print("List is empty")

for user in c_users:
        print ("Hello, " + c_users [0]+"." + " Do you want a status report?")
        statusr=str(input("Y/N: "))
        if  statusr == "Y" or "y":
            print("The status report is being drafted")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            sys.stdout.write(".")
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.stdout.write(".")
            time.sleep(1)
            sys.stdout.write(".")
            time.sleep(2)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.flush()
            print("\n")

        elif statusr == "N" or "n":
            print("No status report today, OK.")
        else:
            print("error")
        time.sleep(10)
        print(actually_new_users)
        ##print ("Hello, " + str(c_users))
        ##time.sleep(0.5)
        ##print ("Hello, " + c_users [2])
        ##time.sleep(0.5)
        ##print ("Hello, " + c_users [3])
        ##time.sleep(0.5)
        ##print ("Hello, " + c_users [4])
        break
```

Comment: You wouldn't loop at all, you'd use sets. If you want a more specific answer, you'll need to post some code.

Comment: s = set.intersection(s1, s2, s3) for multiple lists

Comment: @VeltzerDoron: `s1` is required to be a `set`.

Comment: s =set.intersection(set(l1), set(l2), set(l3)) if you're reading them as lists :)

Comment: Also, why doesn't sys.stdout.flush work with the dots? If I wanted it to become three dots in line with sleep inbetween, and then remove them with flush.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by someone in a comment, a list isn't the most appropriate data structure to store this information in. When you want to make sure that members of one collection aren't present in another collection, you should use a `set` which will enforce this.

If you are insistent upon having lists then the easiest thing to do is

```
current_users = ["bob", "sally"]
new_users = ["harry",  "sally"]
current_users = list(set(current_users).union(set(new_users)))
print(current_users)

>>> ['bob', 'sally', 'harry']
```

Here `.union()` is being used to update the `current_users` with the users in `new_users` that are actually new. If you want to know which users in `new_users` are already in `current_users` then you can use `.intersection()` like so

```
actually_new_users = list(set(new_users) - set(current_users))
print(actually_new_users)

>>> ['harry']
```

This is somewhat inefficient because it will result in a lot of copying, BUT it's still likely better than an `O(n^2)` comparison between two lists*.

*Depending on the size of the lists.

Comment: If OP changes `current_users` to be a `set` we can dispense with a lot of complexity and just do `current_users.update(new_users)`.

Comment: But why doesn't the list c_users update when the n_users is added to c_users?
And if I where to do a set, which I don't even know what it is, how does it differ from list?

Comment: @undergroundczar:  Can you say that question in code?  Do you mean why doesn't `c_users + n_users` change `c_users`?  If that's your question it's because list + list creates a new list.